# Get details about pivot column [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, database-relations

I have 3 tables: `Project`, `Group`, `User`

and one relation pivot table: `project_group` with colmuns:
`id`
`project_id`
`group_id`
and pivot field `user_id`

I know how to take all Groups and Projects:

```
Project::find(1)->groups()->get();
```

`groups()` is belongToMany function inside Project Model.

Problem is I don't know how to get all users for particular project. I need to get project and all users names and ids for that project, any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try on your `Project.php` model adding a pivot relationship

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\User::class, 'project_group');
}
```

---

However this may be misleading as `project_group` should be a pivot table between the `project` table and the `group` table. `user_id` doesn't belong in there.

Create a second pivot table called `group_user` with `group_id`, `user_id`. Then you can use this on your `Group.php` model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\User::class, 'group_user');
}
```

An example would then be:

```
$project = Project::find(1);
foreach($project->groups as $group) {
    $users = $group->users; // Now you should have access to all the users for each group
}
```